# How to graph this sin equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions

I have the following `sin` equation which I am supposed to graph: `sin(3x) = -1` and also find how many solutions it contains between `0` and `2π`. Seeing this I am a bit confused as I don't understand what I am supposed to do with the `-1`. Usually when I graphed these they just equaled `y`. This said this is what I tried:

A (amplitude): 1

B (the stretch/compression amount): 3

P (the period): $\frac{2\pi}{3}$

Note: I found the period by doing $\frac{2\pi}{B}$

Should I bring the -1 on the other side of the equation and let it act as the axis of the wave / mid-line?

Basically my question is: **what should I do with the `-1`? How does it affect the graph?**

Comment: Just graph $y=\sin(3x)$, then find the points where the $y$-coordinate is $-1$. The problem was badly stated

Comment: The edit made to the question kind of changes things...

Comment: @turkeyhundt the edit completely changed my problem. I am not sure why it was made.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can think of it also as, Where do $y=\sin{(3x)}$ and $y=-1$ intersect.

Answer (score 1):

You should graph $y = \sin(3x) + 1$ and look at the points where $y = 0$, i.e. the points where the graph crosses the y-axis.

**Edit:** As Edward Jiang pointed out in the comments, the above is technically incorrect. You are asked to graph $\sin(3x) = -1$. Hence, to find the values of $x$ that solve this equation, just graph $y = \sin(3x)$ and find the points where the graph crosses the line $y = -1$. However, what I wrote above will give the same answers.

Comment: Technically, that's the wrong graph...

Comment: How so? Is it not equivalent?

Comment: Oh, I misread the question. Sorry! However, this will give equivalent values for $x$.

Comment: @EdwardJiang I had this same idea in my mind. Why is this wrong?

Comment: The graph is shifted one unit up. It gives equivalent values of $x$, but the graph is wrong.